# Counting the number of paths of a given length in the graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

The problem and question are as follows:
Given the graph [image: Graph]

"Provide $A$ the adjacency matrix for the graph. Furthermore, provide a matrix B that shows information on how many paths with length $3$ there are from $d$ to every other node. And write all the paths from $d$ to $c$."

I have calculated the adjacency matrix to:

[image: Adjacency matrix A]

And I took $A^3$

[image: B=A^3]

to calculate the number of paths with length three. But when I try to write down the paths from $d$ to $c$, I can´t even come up with one path with a length of three. I´m really confused and would really appreciate some help.

//Lukas

Comment: What did you get for $A^3$?

Comment: D to F to D to C has length 3. Problem did not say illegal for path to use same node twice. [there's another length 3 path from D to C]

Comment: I got A^3 to:  [2     3     4     5     0     1     0;
     3     0     1     1     0     1     0;
     4     1     2     4     0     1     0;
     5     1     4     2     0     3     0;
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1;
     1     1     1     3     0     0     0;
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0]

Comment: So in row 4 column 3 is a 2, meaning 2 paths length 3 from D (node 4) to C (node 3).

Comment: Row 4 column 3 is a 4.

Comment: Lucas: You're right it is a 4.

Comment: For me, it does not look possible to come up with more than one way to travel from node d to node c. And that is as you mentioned earlier d-f-d-c. But I´m not sure if that is even a valid answer, because in previous question they assume that the path can´t go backwards.

Comment: If at any point your text said paths can't double back, then it is not correct. whenever the n-th power of the adjacency matrix is used for paths of length n doubling back is *definitely* allowed. Just consider how matrix multiplication is defined.  I see three paths. DFDC, DADC, DCDC. [I don''t now see a fourth path. can you check that entry?]

Comment: Found the fourth: DCAC.

Comment: Ok, I´m going to ask the professor at my university tomorrow regarding that issue with the specifics in the question. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Yes, ask prof. I'd suggest showing your computation of matrix A, of the cube of that, and the four paths I mentioned in above comments, pointing out that every one of the four paths found contain some letter twice.

Comment: By the way my calculator computation of the cube of adjacency matrix matches what you wrote in your comment at every entry.

Comment: $(A^k)_{i,j}$ counts the number of walks, not paths, of lenght $k$ from $i$ to $j$ in the graph that $A$ represents. It is easy to prove this by induction.